# jsonデータをmonacaに表示させたい

Tags: php, monaca, mysql, json

表題の通りjsonデータをmonacaに表示させたいと思います。

MANP環境ではphpでjson_encodeして上手くMySQLデータをhtmlに反映できたのですが、
そっくりそのままMonacaで試したところjsonデータが引っ張ってこれてない状況に陥りました。
(json_encodeするphpファイルはサーバーにアップ済みです。)

▼ソースコード▼

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://○○△△.jp/json.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json){
    var len = json.length;
    for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
      $("#a").append(json[i].id + ' ' + json[i].○○ + ' ' + json[i].△△ + '<br>');
    }
  }
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

---

2015/12/23/18:26
回答からコードを書き換えました。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="components/monaca-jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script>
        $.ready('deviceready',function(){
            //Ajax通信
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://○○△△.jp/json.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json){
                    var len = json.length;
                    for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
                              $("#a").append(json[i].id + ' ' + json[i].○○ + '<br>');
                    }
                }
                //下記を追加してどう言ったエラーが発生しているのか確認する
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //ステータスコード：エラーに来る際はたいてい200以外
                    //今回の場合は正常なJSON以外でも此方に来る
                    console.log("XMLHttpRequest : " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    //実際のレスポンス
                    //出力された文字列がJSON形式にのっとっているか見る
                    console.log("textStatus : " + textStatus);
                    //どうしてエラーが発生したのかのメッセージ
                    console.log("errorThrown : " + errorThrown.message);
                }
            });
        },false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: 新規で作ったプロジェクトですか？それともアップデートしたプロジェクトですか？

Comment: @Myaku

Myaku様
新規で作ったプロジェクトでございます。

Comment: 追記しましたので、ajaxでどう言ったエラーが発生しているか確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？現状だと環境なのかも……と曖昧なことしか言えません。

Answer (score 2):

考えられる原因として１つめは
WhiteListの関係で接続できないのかもしれないので`index.html`のmetaに下記が追加されているか確認してください。

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

2つ目はコールバックに`success`しかないので`error`も追加してみて何が悪いか切り分けてみてはいかがでしょうか？
オプションの`dataType`に`json`が指定されているので、PHPのWARNINGなどが出力されていてjson構造を認識できないとエラーが発生します。
この場合上記の受け方ですと`success`に入らないので応答が全くないかと思います。
`dataType`外して`success`に入るか試してみてはいかがでしょうか？
(※その場合`JSON.parse`でもエンコードできませんが)

---

**追記：15/12/24**
`index.html`の全文って下記のような感じなるかと思うのですが、
`loader.js`より前に記述すると`monaca`の機能をロードする前に走っちゃうのでおかしくなるかと
あと、jqueryはmonacaのプラグインからインポート出来たりします(好みによるかと思いますが……)
jQueryを使わない方向でイベントをセットしてみました。こちらでどうでしょうか？
もしかしたらjQueryのロードよりも先にセットしているのやも？

PHP側

```
<?php
    $outputs = array(
                    array("id"=>"dammy1", "optA"=>"test1-A", "optB"=>"test1-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy2", "optA"=>"test2-A", "optB"=>"test2-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy3", "optA"=>"test3-A", "optB"=>"test3-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy4", "optA"=>"test4-A", "optB"=>"test4-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy5", "optA"=>"test5-A", "optB"=>"test5-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy6", "optA"=>"test6-A", "optB"=>"test6-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy7", "optA"=>"test7-A", "optB"=>"test7-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy8", "optA"=>"test8-A", "optB"=>"test8-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy9", "optA"=>"test9-A", "optB"=>"test9-B"),
                    array("id"=>"dammy10", "optA"=>"test10-A", "optB"=>"test10-B")
                );
    echo json_encode($outputs);
?>
```

Monaca側

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
                $("#a").append('on device ready.<br>');
                //Ajax通信
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://host_name/json.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json){
                        var len = json.length;
                        for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
                            $("#a").append(JSON.stringify(json[i]) + '<br>');
                        }
                    },
                    //下記を追加してどう言ったエラーが発生しているのか確認する
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //ステータスコード：エラーに来る際はたいてい200以外
                        //今回の場合は正常なJSON以外でも此方に来る
                        $("#a").append("XMLHttpRequest : " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                        //実際のレスポンス
                        //出力された文字列がJSON形式にのっとっているか見る
                        $("#a").append("textStatus : " + textStatus);
                        //どうしてエラーが発生したのかのメッセージ
                        $("#a").append("errorThrown : " + errorThrown.message);
                    }
                });
            },false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="a"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: でも画像]

Comment: Myaku 様

この度はご教示誠にありがとうございます。
Myaku様のアドバス通り試してみます。

Comment: 不明点があった場合は上記のエラーに流れた引数を質問に追記してコメントをくださいな。もし、それ以前の問題でエラーにすら入らなかった場合、そもそも`$.ajax`までたどり着いているか怪しいです。

Comment: Myaku様
ご親切にありがとうございます。
Myaku様のエラーコードを設置しましたが、monaca上でalertやconsoleに出力されませんでしたので、$.ajaxでしょうか。
何か、クリックイベントなど必要なのでしょうか？

http://program-study.hatenablog.com/entry/20130110/1357826840
（このページのpage.htmlソースにある$("*[name=btn]").clickのようなクリックイベント）

初心者でご迷惑をおかけしますがご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 上記のコードって`index.html`にダイレクトで記載していたりしますか？

Comment: Myaku様

はい。
$.ajax({〜のコードはindex.htmlにダイレクトに記載しております。

Comment: 追記しました。一度ご確認いただければ……

Comment: @Myaku様
Myaku様

ご教示ありがとうございます。
試したところ、iPhone実機で「Unexpected identifier 'error'」というlogが表示されました。

Comment: 私のサンプルが悪かったです。すみません。`error`の直前の`success`の閉じタグに`,`が足りません、オプション値のひとつですので必要です。

Comment: Myaku様
ご教示ありがとうございます。
オプション値の一つなのですね。勉強になります。
お陰様で、エラーが消えました。
しかし、画面が真っ白な状態のままでCSSのせいなのかと色々と悩んでます・・・。

Comment: 恐らくエラーの方に入っているかと思います。ただ、エラーの内容がconsole.logのままだとクラウドのIDEで確認するしかないので少し追記修正しました。HTMLに出すならこうかな？多分HTMLステータスコードが200以外か、JSON形式の文字列じゃないと思います。

Comment: Myaku様
何度もありがとうございます。
HTMLに出すように修正しましたが、未だ画面が真っ白の状態です。。。
出力できないということは根本的な部分が間違っているのですね・・・。

Comment: 追記しました。もしかしたらイベントのセットでこけているのかもしれないので普通にJavaScriptでイベントをセットしました。……後、ちゃんと確認しましたorz。流れとしてはドキュメント、またはデバイスの準備が出来てからAjax通信ですかね。ユーザのアクションマターにするのならボタン設置してOnClickが良いと思います。

Comment: Myaku様
ご返信遅くなり誠に申し訳ございません。
Myaku様のご指導により無事monacaにjasonコードを吐き出すことができました。
初心者に手取り足取り丁寧に教えていただき本当にありがとうございました。
これを機にもっともっと上を目指していく活力が湧きました。
本当にありがとうございました。